# While trying to remove entry from Context I get "The property 'id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. "

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I get the following exception while trying remove an entry from my Context:

> The property 'id_db' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

```
var entriesInDB = getAllMatchingEntriesFromDatabase(entryToBeDeleted);
        if (entriesInDB.Any())
        {
            if(entryToBeDeleted.id_db != 0)
            {
                _dbContext.tbl_final.Remove(entryToBeDeleted);
                _logger.RemovedOrder(entryToBeDeleted);
            } else
            {
                _dbContext.tbl_final.Remove(entriesInDB.First());
                _logger.RemovedOrder(entriesInDB.First());
            }

            return true;
        }else
        {
            _logger.NoCorrespondingDatabaseEntryFoundWhileDeleting(entryToBeDeleted);
            return false;
        }
```

The getAllMatchingEntriesFromDatabase function just queries the context to find an existing entry with custom matching criteria.

I did not change the primary key nor do I have the intention to change any property. Why is this error thrown?

Comment: Can you potentially get more than one entity back from a method called "getAllMatchingEntriesFromDatabase"?  Does entityTobeDeleted match the entity in tbl_final?  What are you trying to accomplish with "_dbContext.tbl_final.Remove(entriesInDB.First());"?